# Stack cable connection concept in Cisco switch

Tags: switch, layer1, cable

Can you please share the concept of stack cable connection concept with redundancy and without for all kind of cisco switches, concept for if we have four switches in the same rack and if we have 8 switches in the same rack.
I'm not bother about cable distance and I want know the exact concept to connect the stack cables from stack 1 &2 to another switch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Cisco hardware, the stack concept is the same for all ranges of switches.

You typically always stack Switch 1, port A to Switch 2, port B and then Switch 1, port B to Switch 2, port A.

Illustrations:

[image]

[image]

[image]

As long as you cross the cables as shown on the pictures it does not matter if you start with A to B or B to A when you finish off the stack.

You should prioritize your switches, so that you know who will be master if a switch breaks down in the stack. For instance i would:

```
switch 1 priority 8
switch 2 priority 7
switch 3 priority 6
switch 4 priority 5
switch 5 priority 4
switch 6 priority 3
switch 7 priority 2
switch 8 priority 1
```

Highest priority (number) wins and will be master.

Cisco PowerStack:

If you want to use power stacking, then the concept is also the same:

Cable:

[image]

Stacking method:

[image]